# Passing an array initializer as a method argument is not allowed

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

When I try to pass an array initializer as a method argument I get an error with the message 'Array initializer is not allowed here'.

`methodTakingArrayArgument({0,0,0})`

However, the construct works when the type is mentioned explicitly.

`methodTakingArrayArgument(new int[]{0,0,0})`

Is there a reason that this construct is not supported? There seems to be no documentation on the oracle website mentioning the same.

Edit:
I understand that there are a fixed number of ways to create an array in Java. The array initializer construct felt natural to be supported as a first class citizen in Java, like in languages like typescript.

As one of the answers has pointed out, the array initializer is not a valid expression, which is why it cannot be passed on to a method.

Comment: I don't think there's a "reason" aside from Java not supporting this syntax. (Maybe there's a grammar or type ambiguity reason, but it seems unlikely that this would have been documented.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm really curious if there's a *reason*. Like people link the spec and stuff, OK, I get that this is how it works. But *why*? I don't think there's any particular reason that the compiler can get the type when the array is declared as a variable but it couldn't do the same for a method parameter - which also has to have a type. It's an interesting (and in my opinion, kinda user unfriendly) language design choice. Perhaps they want to enforce clarity, so that the actual type is always nearby when using this syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) is the final authority on such questions: [Chapter 15 Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) in general,  [§15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) and [§15.10.1. Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) and [10.6. Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) in particular. 
In a nutshell, what you'll discover is:

1. The argument list of a method invocation consists of a series of comma-separated *expression*;
2. `new int[]{0,0,0}` is an *arrayCreationExpression*, which, in turn, is a type of *expression* and thus allowable as an argument in a method invocation;
3. `{0,0,0}` is an *arrayInitializer* which, by itself, is not an *expression* and thus not legal to use as an argument in a method invocation.